# Flutter SDK installed, but not found (windows)

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

Flutter Doctor -v indicates SDK is there.
(for some reason it says Android Studio is not installed)

```
**[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0 at C:\Users\kaste\Documents\flutter
    • Framework revision b22742018b (3 weeks ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
    • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
    • Dart version 2.13.0
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\kaste\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\kaste\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\kaste\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.22.0
[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
    • Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.37**
```

In Android Studio, I get this error message when trying to start a new Flutter App.
[Android Studio error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkM2G.png)

I can't figure out why it's not working.  I can run the default Android Studio flutter app in the Android Virtual Device fine.

?

Comment: can you share your flutter sdk path ?

Comment: Did you set the flutter path in Android Studio ?

Comment: Solved!  Thank you!  I changed the path to "C:\Users\kaste\Documents\flutter" and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

same thing happened to me when i pointed the path
as

```
/home/ekele/flutter_sdk/bin
```

it worked when i changed it to

```
/home/pompidou/flutter_sdk
```

change the path below to *C:\Users\kaste\Documents\flutter*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you need to set 'flutter installation directory' (you got it as can be shown at your `flutter doctor -v` command output:
Flutter version 2.2.0 at C:\Users\kaste\Documents\flutter.
Problem is you are setting as flutter SDK your Android SDK installation directory, which is wrong. You need to just set `C:\Users\kaste\Documents\flutter` instead of `C:\Users\kaste\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`